# How to generate sequential GUIDs?

Tags: php, mysql, guid

Are there PHP libraries to generate sequential GUIDs for usage in a MySQL database?

Comment: Wouldn't MySQL's auto-increment capability suit your needs there?

Comment: GUIDs aren't supposed to have a meaningful order - why do they need to be sequential?

Comment: Sequential GUIDs may perform better when using as primary key. At least that's what I've heard (and I can imagine it's true).

Comment: @Romain Muller: Sure this is simpler, but there are some disadvantages to auto-increment keys, like cross-db merging, security (visitors or spambots iterate over your id's and get to every user, you may not want that), etc.

Comment: why is that? Where have you read it (it, in fact, makes no sense at all)?

Comment: How is iterating over a Sequential ID more secure than iterating over sequential Ints? GUIDs are considered secure because they are non-predictable (if implemented correctly)

Comment: @opencat; isn't it true that sequential GUID's are unique in the table itself, but not across the whole database (therefore, not being GUID but rather UID) and wouldn't merging still be a problem? A prefix to each ID would solve this. Also just using GUID's (without sequence) would.

Comment: No, depending on the algorithm (there isn't _the_ algorithm for seq.guids) they are guaranteed to be at least unique throughout the same machine. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier#Sequential_Algorithms and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx (and many more) There are also several "threads" on sequential guids here on SO, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170346/what-are-the-performance-improvement-of-sequential-guid-over-standard-guid

Comment: There are several forms of GUIDs. In far past, most GUIDs were linked to a MAC address of a network card in the machine, plus a time signature, plus a time-change counter, plus a sequential component. These things together insured global uniqueness.

After a while privacy concerns brought us the now-common "random" GUID which is VERY bad for key-splitting/index rebalancing.

Comment: @Doug GUID can be both random and sequential. They are supposed to be sequential if you intend to use them in a clustered index. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757222/should-a-sequential-guid-primary-key-column-be-a-clustered-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean uuids based on a common prefix, such as MAC and time, have a look at [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php). Here you can also find some code for RFC 4211 compliant UUIDS. If you want to be on the safe side, use this wrapper to libuuid: [pecl uuid](http://pecl.php.net/package/uuid). Haven't tested it though, YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what is being asked for is, does MySQL have support for Sequential Id's the way that SQL Server does?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2010/05/27/guid-vs-int-debate.aspx

Now before everyone asks why use GUIDS, GUIDS will allow one to move/merge data between tables and databases.